# New to SQL and already having an issue

Tags: sql

I'm doing a group project to learn SQL, I'm using jdoodle as an online IDE for now and w3schools. I feel so weird for asking this because this is literally my first attempt but I get an error.

```
CREATE DATABASE turing;
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
    SupplierNumber int,
    SupplierName varchar(255),
    SupplierAddress varchar(255),
);
Error: near line 1: in prepare, near "DATABASE": syntax error (1)
Error: near line 2: in prepare, near ")": syntax error (1)
```

I'm just like copying exactly what w3schools taught me?

Comment: jdoodle doesn't let you create a new database with SQL

Comment: What's the second error then? How can I easily do SQL?

Comment: remove the last comma

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in here, But these are some best practises,

1. RUN the SQL queries one by one in case if that's causing the error. First create the Database and then Create the Table. Do both seperately.

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
    supplierNumber int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    supplierName varchar(255),
    supplierAddress varchar(255)
);
```

2. Best practise is to have the column names in lowerCamelCase.
   Normally we don't use comma for the last line. It is Unnecessary
3. Having a Primary key for every table is good. Make it PRIMARY KEY and NOT NULL at the same time to prevent some error in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In an online editor (at least at [jdoodle.com](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/) and w3schools.com) you can't create a new database!

Answer (score 0):

After creating the database , you should use the code USE turing;
this allows SQL to make the data base active for the given program to run.
also remove the last ',' comma.